How many subgroups of order 25 are contained in this group?
Let $G = C_{15} \times C_{50}$. How many subgroups of order $25$ does $G$ contain?
I immediately thought of cyclic groups, so I counted the elements of order $25$. $(x,y)$ with $x \in C_{15}$ and $y \in C_{50}$ has order $25$ iff $|y| = 25$ and $(|x| = 1$ or $|x| = 5)$ and using Euler's totient function I found that there are $100$ elements of order $25$ in G, distributed into $5$ cyclic subgroups. This is correct, but there is one more (non-cyclic) subgroup of order $25$ which I have no idea how to find.
Can you, by any chance, recommend a book with exercises similar to this?

What is $\langle a\rangle$, where $a$ is "something" with $|a|=15$? Why not explicitly writing $\Bbb Z/15$ (or for pedant readers and writers $\Bbb Z/(15)$)?

That's how it was written in the exercise sheet. Might as well be $\mathbb{Z}/15$.

Even better, not to confuse with the rings, your group is just $G=C_{15}\times C_{50}$. Since $25=p^2$, there is only one other non-cyclic group of order $25$, namely $C_5\times C_5$.

Oh...thank you. I thought you guys were just being annoying, but writing it like that actually is helpful. Thanks!

Comment:
Among the cyclic subgroups are somewhat hidden fiber products as described in  Goursat's lemma. These are also known as pullbacks in category theory.
The single noncyclic one is forced by the universal property of the direct product.

Let $G_1=\langle a\rangle$ be the group generated by $a$ with relation $a^{15}=1$.
Let $G_2=\langle b\rangle$ be the group generated by $b$ with relation $a^{50}=1$.
We use the multiplication as the operation in both of them.
Let $G$ be the cartesian product $G=G_1\times G_2$, and we identify $a$ from $G_1$ with the element $(a,1)\in G$, consider in this manner $G_1$ as a subgroup of $G$. The same applies also for $b\in G_2$, seen as $(1,b)\in G$.
Note: By the theorem of invariant factors we can see $G$ as isomorphic with $\Bbb Z/5\times \Bbb Z/150$.
Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $25$. Then its structure is either $\Bbb Z/5\times \Bbb Z/5$ or $\Bbb Z/25$. In the first case we need two (independent) generators of order $5$ each.  In the second case we need one generator of order $25$.
It is easy to find them, since there are only a few expressions of the form $a^jb^k$.
To have a list of them, and to have them quickly typed, i will use the computer, the engine is sage, in fact a bundle of engines collected under one hat.
sage: G = AbelianGroup(2, [15, 50], names='ab')
sage: [H for H in G.subgroups() if H.order() == 25]
[Multiplicative Abelian subgroup isomorphic to C5 x C5 generated by {a^3, b^10},
 Multiplicative Abelian subgroup isomorphic to C25 generated by {a^3*b^2},
 Multiplicative Abelian subgroup isomorphic to C25 generated by {a^9*b^2},
 Multiplicative Abelian subgroup isomorphic to C25 generated by {a^6*b^2},
 Multiplicative Abelian subgroup isomorphic to C25 generated by {a^12*b^2},
 Multiplicative Abelian subgroup isomorphic to C25 generated by {b^2}]

From here, details can be traced back...
